# How do I extract the numbers from the last column in a txt file in python?

Tags: python, file

I have a file that looks like this (the last column has more or less space in between the previous one randomly):

```
Name    LastName    Age
Adrian   Smith      101
Martin   Ville  82
Mary     Morre          9
```

I want to extract only the ages so I can put them inside a set.

I have tried this so far but I only get random one digit numbers:

```
age = set()
for line in f:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit():
    age.update(i)
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code line by line with the debugger and examine the type and value of i.

Comment: To add on, it scans each character, meaning you will get 1,8,9

Comment: @chess_lover_6 Yes, that's what I noticed. How can I just get the numbers in each line?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting one digit numbers because you only check one digit at a time. For example, when the code reaches the first number, it will first look at "1", then "0" and then "1", and add them each as individual numbers, rather than one number: 101.

It would be easier to split each line into a list of each word in the line, and then add the last word in the list to your set. You could do that with `line.split(" ")` (which would also leave you with a load of empty strings in the list since there are multiple spaces, but they can be ignored).

```py
age = set()
for idx, line in enumerate(f):
    if idx == 0:  # ignore first line
        continue
    line = line.split(" ")
    number = int(line[-1])
    age.add(number)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it returns this when I try it: "   for line in f[1:]:
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable "

Comment: Ah. I (wrongly) assumed `f` was a list. Hopefully my edit solves the error.